# angular2-highchart line-chart showing wrong values on y-axis

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm using a **angular2-highchart** line-chart on Angular 6 application which displays active users by date on the graph.

[image]

It's pretty straighforward but I have an issue with y-axis. The values on right are completely different from the actual values shown on the line.

```js
      chart: {
        redraw: false,
        zoomType: this.rangeEnabled ? 'x' : null,
        type: 'spline',
        alignTicks: false
      },
      title: {
        text: this.title
      },
      plotOptions: {
        spline: {
          marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
          }
        },
        series: {
          compare: this.showByPercent ? 'percent' : 'value'
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        // minRange: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
      },
      xAxis: {
        // min: 0,
        minRange: 1,
        allowDecimals: false
        // ceiling: 100
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        enabled: this.rangeEnabled,
        // selected: 2,
        allButtonsEnabled: true,
        buttons: [
          {
            type: 'week',
            count: 1,
            text: '1w'
          },
          {
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m'
          },
          {
            type: 'month',
            count: 3,
            text: '3m'
          },
          {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y'
          },
          {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
          }
        ]
      },
      navigator: {
        enabled: this.navigatorEnabled,
        adaptToUpdatedData: false
      },
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: this.navigatorEnabled,
        scrollbar: {
          liveRedraw: false
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        split: false,
        xDateFormat: this.preciseTooltipDate ? undefined : '%A, %b %e, %Y'
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: this.legendEnabled,
        title: { text: 'Filters' },
        // layout: 'vertical',
        // align: 'bottom',
        // verticalAlign: 'middle',
        useHTML: true,
        floating: false
      },
      exporting: {
        // allowHTML: true,
        buttons: {
          contextButton: {
            enabled: this.download,
            symbol: 'download'
          }
        }
      },
      series: series
```

And the *series* variable is just an array of data, which is formatted like this:

`[date:number, value:number]`.

The weird thing is that with some data-sets, its not that far off from the expected value, and with others its completely wrong.

Comment: Perhaps your series array can be wrong. It should be an array with series objects where property data is an array of arrays like this [date, value]. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/4wqojL85/.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Thank you for the answer but I just managed to fix it by commenting out the plotOptions object from chart options. Doesn't make any sense but it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯